# $\{X_i\}$ i.d normally distributed r.v.$E(X_n)=0,Var(X_n)=1+1/n$,judge whether $\{X_n\}$ satisfies CLT?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_i\}$ be **independent normally** distributed random variables.$E(X_n)=0,Var(X_n)=1+1/n$,judge whether $\{X_n\}$ satisfies CLT(central limit theorem) conclusion,i.e,$S_n/\sqrt {Var(S_n)}\to\mathcal N(0,1)$ in distribution?

Attempts:I tried the Lindeberg condition,but I think it is hard to estimate this sum:$\frac{1}{c_n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{|X_k|\geq\epsilon c_n} x_k^2dF_k(x)$,which $\geq\epsilon^2\sum_{k=1}^nP(|X_k|\geq\epsilon c_n)$,but that seems unable to give an answer.

Also I tried the Liapounov's condition,but I haven't found the proper $\delta$ yet.

Comment: You mean $S_n/\sqrt{V[S_n]}$?

Comment: @Snoop Yes,I will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use Lindeberg condition or Liapounov's condition in this particular situation. From the properties of normal distribution, we have:

$S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(E(S_n),Var(S_n)^2)$

$E(S_n)=E(X_1)+\ldots+E(X_n)=0$

$Var(S_n)^2=Var(X_1)^2+\ldots+var(X_n)^2=(1+1)^2+\ldots+(1+\frac{1}{n})^2$

Then we just get $S_n/\sqrt{Var(S_n)}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ directly.

Comment: :Two things. 1) You should take the squares out of the third line because it may confuse people who are reading your answer. 2) I don't think the question is as straightforward as it initially seems because the variance is changing with increasing $n$ so you can't just put it in the denominator. It's different for each $n$. Unfortunately, answering the question is beyond my pay grade. :).

Comment: @markleeds what does 'Unfortunately, answering the question is beyond my pay grade' mean?

Comment: @markleeds It doesn't count whether $n$ is changable or not, because for every certain n, $S_n/\sqrt{Var(S_n)}$ is just exactly $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. That's also the property of normal distribution.

Comment: I'm sorry snoop. I was trying to be funny but it's an american funny so probably not very funny. my apologies ( it's too hard to explain right now why it could be funny ). actually, given your other answers and abilities, I'm hoping that you can provide an answer.

Comment: @Galaxy: I think it matters but I understand what you are doing. You are saying that one can calculate the variance at each $n$ and use that. My guess is that is not what the question is asking. I think the question is saying that the expression  converges independently of $n$ because $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$. Maybe the approach of cryptoguy4561 is the way to proceed.

Comment: @markleeds Which expression converges? $S_n/\sqrt{Var(S_n)}$?

Comment: @markleeds with characteristic functions (same with mgf) if you denote with $\sigma_n^2=\textrm{Var}[S_n]$ we get

$$E[e^{i\xi S_n/\sigma_n}]=\prod_{k\leq n}E[e^{i\xi X_k/\sigma_n}]=\prod_{k\leq n}e^{-\xi^2(1+1/k)/(2\sigma_n^2)}=e^{-(\xi^2/(2\sigma_n^2))\sum_{k\leq n}(1+1/k)}=e^{-\xi^2/2}$$

Since $E[e^{i\xi S_n/\sigma_n}]\to e^{-\xi^2/2}$ trivially for all $\xi $ real, we have convergence in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: @snoop: thanks but a dopey question.( recall that my pay grade is low ). How did the $\sum_{k \le n}\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)$ disappear in the last step.

Comment: @snoop: also, it's not my thread or question but I think that your comment could be made into an answer since it addresses the OP's question directly.

Comment: @markleeds $\sigma_n^2=\sum_{k\leq n}(1+1/k)$ because the variance of the sum $S_n$ is the sum of the variances due to independence

Comment: Nice. So it cancels out the one in the bottom which means that the characteristic function is no longer a function of $n$. So, does that mean that it's true all the time and not just in the limit ? If that's the case, then Galaxy was correct and my apologies to him. Thanks for derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that the moment-generating function of $X_n$ converges to a normal one.

Could also show that the CDF converges, but up to you. Lindeberg would be overkill.